# How to Specify (give an actual name) XML fields in Java (Apache CXF)

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jaxb

Operation is JAVA to WSDL. I am creating a SOAP Webservice.

I generated a SOAP webservice and the attributes look like this:

```
         <arg0>?</arg0>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg1>?</arg1>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg2>?</arg2>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg3>?</arg3>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg4>?</arg4>
```

What XML annotation should I use to specify them to look these like instead:

```
<name> </name>
<age> </age>
<location> </location>
```

Let's say

```
String age = "";
String name = "";
String location = "";
```

Do I use

```
@XmlAttribute(name="age")
String age = "";
@XmlAttribute(name="name")
String name = "";
@XmlAttribute(name="location ")
String location = "";
```

I use Apache CXF. Generate WebService -> yada -> yada
in Eclipse.

Basically what Im asking is the XML keyword in charge of "renaming" Java fields fromg arg0 to something specific like "name".

Comment: How do you generate your WS (wsdl->java,java->wsdl?)? ..what annotations do you use so far? Sry, the question is (for me) still unclear/needs more details/info/context.

Comment: so far no annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I've not created a service with CXF, only a client but when using the Apache cxf-codegen-plugin to generate sources from the wsdl the annotation on the object's properties is `@XmlElement(name = "age")`

If a schema type is desired the annotation is `@XmlSchemaType(name = "string")`.

For enums it's `@XmlEnumValue("THE VALUE")`

Hope this helps.